# How to lock WooCommerce date created on administration area

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets

Hello there someone helped me, regarding my case on woocommerce, I want to lock the date created on woocommerce back-end area when you add order on back-end area.

I have found the same case here - [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54359507/woocommerce-disable-date-on-edit-orders)

Is there any available snippets that doesn't require any JavaScript

Comment: The best way would be JavaScript. Because otherwise you need to modify the build function of the page. So when I understand it right, you want to only lock it for created orders, not for orders created by the customers when they buy something?

Comment: Actually only our staff will create orders but only through backend so if javascript is only the way can you show me how to do that...or can you help out with it cause i have no idea how to do it...

Comment: You can disable the input with the help of JavaScript. This is the only way. Otherwise you need to edit the page template. But I think when you have no idea, JavaScript will be the better solution.

Comment: Still there? Can you please check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there we go. You first need to create a `admin.js` file in your child theme. You can put this into a folder named `js`:

```
- ChildTheme
   - js
    - admin.js
```

After this we need to include this file into WordPress. For this you need to put this part of code into your `functions.php` file:

```
/**
 * Add ressources to dashboard page
 */
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_enqueue_styles' );
function admin_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'admin-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/admin.js' );
}
```

Now your `admin.js` is known within the WordPress backend. Open now the file and put this into your file to disable the `date` and `time` input of WooCommerce orders:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".order_data_column .date-picker, .order_data_column .hour, .order_data_column .minute").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Save it and upload it onto your server. Clean the cookies and reload the page. The date and time input should be now disabled. Let me know if it works for you.

**UPDATE**

If you want to use CSS, you should not just disable all date-picker classes. I would be more specific here and just disable the date pickers you really want to disable:

```
.order_data_column .date-picker,
.order_data_column .hour,
.order_data_column .minute {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

And to make it more fancy, you can set the cursor for the wrapper to not-allowd:

```
#order_data .order_data_column .form-field {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

This goes into your `admin.css` file.

Bot solutions are working. Both of them has advantages and disadvantages.

The **JS** solution is HTML based because this sets a `disabled` parameter to each specified input field. This is a *backend-code* solution.

The **CSS** solution don't disables the input at all. You just disable the cursor click to this specific field. So this is a *view-based* solution.

Comment: wait and i will try again on my end...its just I dont know why it doesnt work maybe I did something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this simple CSS to disable that date on order backend...

```
.date-picker {pointer-events: none}
```

Comment: If you would like to use CSS, I would prefer to be a bit more specific. Check my answer.